# odoo 8 Count attachment and show in list view

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I have odoo 8. I want to count the attachment from ir_attachment and and show it in stock.production.lot. Here is my .py

```
class stock_production_lot(models.Model):
_inherit='stock.production.lot'

@api.multi
def get_attachment_info(self):
    for lot in self:
        so_line_ids = self.env['ir.attachment'].search([('res_id','=',lot.id)])
        for pick in so_line_ids:
            pick.count_attachment = 0
            if pick.datas_fname:
                pick.count_attachment = len(pick.datas_fname)

count_attachment = fields.Float(string='Total Attachment', compute='get_attachment_info')
```

and this the view

```
<field name="count_attachment" />
```

Thanks

Comment: Add print in your method and add result in your first message to give more information. Very important, when you search an ir.attachment by res_id. Add res_model in your search because ir.attachment can have 2 time same res_id for 2 different res_model

Comment: What are you trying to do with the following code `pick.count_attachment = len(pick.datas_fname)` and why you are setting the `count_attachment` field  in `ir.attachment` model?

Comment: You really have to think more about your code. Please add some more details, like on which model you're adding the new field. Why do you name an attachment recordset (the search) `so_line_ids`. In "normal" code i would expect a list of IDs of model `sale.order.line` records. Then the second for loop on `so_line_ids`, why are that `pick`s now? And why does a count on attachments needs to be float? Do you expect half attachments?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to answer, because the information in your question are a bit poor. But let me try to answer it in a general way with a general example how i would do it.

Let's say you want a count of all attachments of model `stock.picking` (Delivery Nots, Slips, Receipts, and so on).

So you need to add a computed field, which could be stored, but it's difficult to trigger a recalculation of this field, because attachments are related to records indirectly (no real foreign keys used in database).

```py
class StockPicking(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'stock.picking'

    attachment_count = fields.Integer(compute="_compute_attachment_count")

    @api.multi
    def _compute_attachment_count(self):
        for picking in self:
            domain = [('res_id', '=', picking.id),
                      ('res_model', '=', self._name)]
            picking.attachment_count = self.search_count(domain)
```

And also add the new field to a view of model `stock.picking`.

Now let's pretend that you don't only want the attachments of the pickings but also of their move lines, too.
Just "count" them and add that count to the previous one:

```py
    @api.multi
    def _compute_attachment_count(self):
        for picking in self:
            domain = [('res_id', '=', picking.id),
                      ('res_model', '=', self._name)]
            picking_count = self.search_count(domain)
            if picking.move_lines:
                domain_move = [('res_id', 'in', picking.move_lines.ids),
                               ('res_model', '=', picking.move_lines._name)]
                picking_count += picking.move_lines.search_count(domain_move)
            picking.attachment_count = picking_count
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. I have updated my posting. The problem is that I want to show the attachment count result in stock.production.lot from ir.attachment table. There is no res_id and res_model in my stock.picking table

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the respone. I have got the answer

```
@api.one
def count_attachments(self):
    obj_attachment = self.env['ir.attachment']
    for record in self:
        record.count_attachment = 0
        attachment_ids = obj_attachment.search([('res_model','=',self._name),('res_id','=',record.id)])
        if attachment_ids:
            record.count_attachment = len(attachment_ids)
```